# Why is the equation for Entropy of an ideal gas that undergoes reversible change in $T$ at constant Pressure like this?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, entropy

Why is the equation for change in Entropy for a reversible change in $T$ at constant $P$ described as

$$\Delta S = n C_p \ln\frac{T_f}{T_i}$$

Answer (score 4):

Begin with
$$
  \delta Q = T dS
$$
and recall that the heat transfer for an ideal gas at constant pressure is
$$
  \delta Q = nC_p dT
$$
Combining these gives
$$
  dS = n C_p \frac{dT}{T}
$$
and integrating both sides with respect to temperature from $T_i$ to $T_f$ gives
$$
  S_f - S_i = nC_p \ln\frac{T_f}{T_i}
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the equation
$$
  \Delta S = C_P \ln \frac{T_f}{T_i}
$$
is true for *any* substance undergoing constant pressure heating/cooling, solid, liquid or vapor *as long as there is no phase change* during the process.